# Manage redirect-uri for remote profile editing (via Azure AD B2C)

Tags: asp.net, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-webassembly

I've configured *Azure AD B2C* to manage *Profile Editing* User Flow, to allow users of my application to edit their attributes directly from Azure AD.

The application is a *ASP.NET Blazor WASM* application that uses *MSAL authentication*.

I configured the app in order to let the user change their data navigating to `authentication/profile` page, that redirect to Azure AD profile editing page.

The user can change their profile data and save changes, but I can't found a way to process the returned data (added to the return uri, with a `code` query parameter) from Azure.

Until the next logon the authenticated user claims principal is not updated and display store the old data in user claims.

**How I configured the user flow**

To configure the profile editing experience I followed [Tutorial: Create user flows and custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C - MS Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-user-flow#create-a-profile-editing-user-flow), and then set the `RemoteProfilePath` option inside the `AddMsalAuthentication`, in this way:

```cs
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options => {
        // ... 
        // Set remote profile path to enable profile editing
        var clientId = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:ClientId");
        var returnUrl = $"{builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress}my-profile";
    
        options.AuthenticationPaths.RemoteProfilePath = $"https://myapp.b2clogin.com/" +
                $"myapp.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_ProfileEditingUserFlow" +
                $"&client_id={clientId}&nonce=defaultNonce" +
                $"&redirect_uri={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl)}" +
                $"&scope=openid&response_type=code&prompt=login" +
                $"&code_challenge_method=S256&code_challenge=codespecifictomyapp";
    });
```

After that, when the user navigate to `authentication/profile`, he is redirected to the Azure profile editing modal.

Note that the `Authentication.razor` page is a standard one that uses [`RemoteAuthenticatorView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.authentication.remoteauthenticatorview?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and respond as `@page "/authentication/{action}"`.

The problem is that I would like to process the returned data available in the redirect from Azure, in order to update user attributes.

In fact a `code` query parameter is added to the redirect uri, and the URL looks like this `https://localhost:7173/my-profile?code=eyJraWQiOiJjc...`.

**Tried to set different `redirect_uri`**

Initially, I set the `redirect_uri` to `authentication/login-callback`, but it doesn't work since this *callback* is related to the login action and the component doesn't process the response. The authentication page simply display the `Completing login...` message.

It seems to me that the `RemoteAuthenticatorView` component doesn't manage this scenario, it only manage the `profile` action to redirect to remote url, but then doesn't provide any way to process the response, so I suppose to manage the returned code from my own.

So I set the `my-profile` page, so at least the user is redirect to the user profile page where he started then navigation.
But I stopped here and I don't know how to walk the last mile.

**Checked in the source code for `RemoteAuthenticatorView`**

I checked also the source code for [RemoteAuthenticatorView](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/WebAssembly/WebAssembly.Authentication/src/RemoteAuthenticatorViewCore.cs), but didn't found a solution.

Comment: Did you manage to do this in the end?

Comment: No, at the moment I've solved managing edit profile process directly from the application avoiding the use of `RemoteProfilePath`.

Comment: Using graph api?

Comment: Yes, I directly used API and managed directly user profile data in the back end. It requires additional stuff but I didn't found another soluzione.